# Changing grpc C++ channel host address after creation at runtime

Tags: c++, grpc

I use grpc C++ client in my application. I need a way to change a host address of channel after creation. Is there anyway to do this without creating new channel?

```
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(host_address, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
.....
.....
.....
// User want to change server address. Now how to change channel host address?
```

Comment: What you probably want is a name resolver which pushes an update to the grpc channel with an updated address.

Comment: @EaswarSwaminathan can you give me an example code so I can test it?